# how to merge foreach loop in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am using nested foreach in my blade template, but all records are duplicated. So the code I've tried is the following.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($ordertaker as $ot)
        @foreach($totalorder as $tord)
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{ $ot->total_visit }}/{{ $tord }}
              </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

if in db i have value

total_visit = [10, 30] and sum = [20 , 40]

**then i have output**

10/20

10/20

20/40

20/40

**but required result is**

10/20

20/40

is there a way i can use single loop to get both result example

`@foreach($ordertaker as $ot && $totalorder as $tord)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hope this would work you are using two loops so if you have 2 results then they would be multiplied  that's why you are getting 4 results

```
 <tbody>
        @foreach($ordertaker as $key => $ot)
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {{ $ot->total_visit }}/{{ $totalorder[$key] }}
                  </td>
                </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Wellcome always